# Cancelar todas las subscripciones y tareas asyncronas sin usar useEffect, debe ser solo por handleSubmit

Tags: reactjs, submit

necesito una solución a un problema en mi aplicación del lado Front con REACT, sobre un problema que no he logrado hasta ahora solucionar luego de muchos intentos buscando, dicho problema tiene que ver con el ciclo de vida en los componentes que se maneja en react en este caso para React Hooks para componentes funcionales, tengo un módulo donde realizo un pago con la librería Striper, también uso otra librería llamada Stepper y otras más , pero estas son las importantes ,,,

La secuencia empieza así :
En el paso 1 confirmo el pago ,
En el paso 2 selecciono el método de pago
En el paso 3 se debe realizar el pago primero debo llenar todos los datos en un formulario como : nombre del titular , correo, número de tarjeta y otros campos más ,,, cuando de Click en el botón verifico que todos los campos estén llenos y sean válidos una vez que todo este bien recién se empieza a crear el pago mediante código extraídos de la documentación de Stripe, el tema es que estas llamadas los hace mediante peticiones asyncronas con async y await , cuando verifico que la llamada se hiso correctamente y se reciba una respuesta recién pasaré al último paso del Stepper que sería el paso 4 entonces deberé cambiar a otro componente nuevo donde mostraré un mensaje de Exito por el pago realizado correctamente y desaparecer el componente anterior, pero al momento de cambiar a este nuevo componente recibo este error :

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

ya investigue bastante aplicando distintas soluciones por distintas páginas incluso en stackoverflow , pero todos los ejemplos que veo siempre usan el useEffect para realizar acciones al montar o desmontar el componente ya sea para suscribirse o desuscribirse y cancelar llamadas async con fetch , pero en mi caso no debo usar el useEffect por que no aplica para mi caso , yo necesito limpiar todo en el handleSubmit , repito que ya he aplicado gran variedad de soluciones pero ninguna me ha funcionado ,,,

Aquí dejo mi código resumido

aquí elimine el código de varias variables de estado, simplemente deje las variables de Stepper  y el set para actualizar el estado y cambiar a otro paso del Stepper

```
const useStateGlobal = () => {
    const [steps] = useState(
        [{
            title: 'Confirmar Compra',
            href: 'http://example1.com',
            onClick: (e) => {
                e.preventDefault()
                console.log('onClick', 1)
            }
        }, {
            title: 'Seleccionar tipo de pago',
            href: 'http://example2.com',
            onClick: (e) => {
                e.preventDefault()
                console.log('onClick', 2)
            }
        }, {
            title: 'Detalles de pago',
            href: 'http://example3.com',
            onClick: (e) => {
                e.preventDefault()
                console.log('onClick', 3)
            }
        }, {
            title: 'Compra Finalizada',
            href: 'http://example4.com',
            onClick: (e) => {
                e.preventDefault()
                console.log('onClick', 4)
            }
        }]
    );

    const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(0);
   
    return {
        steps,
        currentStep,setCurrentStep
    }
};
```

Este es mi componente del Stepper ,
El componente Elements es obtenido de la librería Stripe para realizar pagos con tarjeta y el CheckoutForm2 es mi componente personal de un formulario de datos donde al llenar todos los campos y dar click se creará el pago de tarjeta, en este formulario utilizo complementos de la librería Stripe como CardNumberElement ( para el ingreso del número de tarjeta ) etc , gracias al código extraído de la documentación de Stripe ,,, y es aqui mismo donde se produce el error causado por unas llamadas asyncronas de stripe con await ,,,

```
export const Confirmar_Paquete_Stepper = () => {  
        
        const { steps, currentStep, setCurrentStep } = useBetween(useStateGlobal);
        const buttonStyle = { background: '#E0E0E0', width: 200, padding: 16, textAlign: 'center', 
        margin: '0 auto', marginTop: 32 };

        const onClickNext = (e) => {           
            let valor = (currentStep == null || currentStep == 0 )  ? 1 : currentStep+1;           
            setCurrentStep(valor);
        }

         const onClickBack = (e) => {
             let valor = (currentStep == null || currentStep == 0) ? 1 : currentStep - 1;
             setCurrentStep(valor);
         }

        if (currentStep == 0) {
        return (           
               <div id="contenedor-stepper-compra-paquete"> 
                   <Stepper steps={steps} activeStep={currentStep}  />
                <Confirmar_Paquete />
               </div>
        );
        }
        else if (currentStep == 1) {
        return (
               <div id="contenedor-stepper-compra-paquete">
                   <Stepper steps={steps} activeStep={currentStep} />
                   <Seleccionar_Tipo_Pago_Paquete />     
                <div style={buttonStyle} onClick={onClickBack}>Volver</div>
               </div>
        );
        } else if (currentStep == 2) {
            return (
                <div id="contenedor-stepper-compra-paquete">
                    <Stepper steps={steps} activeStep={currentStep}  />

                    <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
                        <CheckoutForm2/>
                    </Elements>
                    <div style={buttonStyle} onClick={onClickBack}>Volver</div>
                </div>
        );
        }   
          else if (currentStep == 3) {
              return (
                  <div id="contenedor-stepper-compra-paquete">
          
                      <Stepper steps={steps} activeStep={currentStep}  />
                      <Finalizar_Compra_Paquete />
                      <div style={buttonStyle} onClick={onClickBack}>Volver</div>
                  </div>
            );
        }  
};
```

Este es mi componente del formulario de pago ,, he borrado varias partes de código , dejando solo las partes primordiales y puedan notar donde y el por que recibo el error

```
 const CheckoutForm2 = () => {    
    const { steps, currentStep, setCurrentStep, token, datos_paquete_seleccionado, setDatos_paquete_seleccionado, camposDatosTarjeta, setcamposDatosTarjeta, formErrors, setformErrors, errores_servTarjeta, seterrores_servTarjeta,
            paseValidacionFormTitularTarjeta, setpaseValidacionFormTitularTarjeta,
            paseValidacionFormCorreoTarjeta, setpaseValidacionFormCorreoTarjeta,
            paseValidacionFormTarjeta, setpaseValidacionFormTarjeta,
            paseValidacionFormFechaExpTarjeta, setpaseValidacionFormFechaExpTarjeta,
            paseValidacionFormCvcTarjeta, setpaseValidacionFormCvcTarjeta,
            paseValidacionFormCiudadTarjeta, setpaseValidacionFormCiudadTarjeta,
        paseValidacionFormCodigoPostalTarjeta, setpaseValidacionFormCodigoPostalTarjeta
       } = useBetween(useStateGlobal);
    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();
    const titularTarjetaRegex = RegExp(
        /^[A-Za-z\s]+$/
    );
    const emailRegex = RegExp(
        /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
    );
    const codigopostalTarjetaRegex = RegExp(
        /^[0-9]+$/
    );
    const ciudadTarjetaRegex = RegExp(
        /^[A-Za-z]+$/
    );

    
    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            
        };
    }, []);

    const HandleValidar = async (event) => {
          Aqui borre todo el código, pero simplemente valido cada campo del formulario por el evento onChange , que es el que llama a esta función 
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
       Aqui es donde está todo mi código que se ejecuta cuando presione el botón de click que llamará a handleSubmit

        event.preventDefault();        
        const { titular_tarjeta, correo_tarjeta, ciudad_tarjeta, codigo_postal_tarjeta } = event.target;  
        
Aqui dejaré solo un ejemplo de como valido cada campo de mi formulario , por ejemplo aqui valido el campo del titular de la tarjeta
        //TITULAR TARJETA
        if (titular_tarjeta.value.length < 3) {           
            setformErrors(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "Ingrese mínimo 3 caracteres"
         }));
            seterrores_servTarjeta(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "" }));
            setpaseValidacionFormTitularTarjeta("NO");            
        }
        else if (!titularTarjetaRegex.test(titular_tarjeta.value)) {            
            setformErrors(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "Formato de nombres inválido" 
         }));
            seterrores_servTarjeta(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "" }));
            setpaseValidacionFormTitularTarjeta("NO");
            
        }
        else if (titular_tarjeta.value.length > 22) {
            setformErrors(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "Ingrese maximo 22 caracteres" 
        }));
            seterrores_servTarjeta(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "" }));
            setpaseValidacionFormTitularTarjeta("NO");
        }
        else {
            setformErrors(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "" }));
            seterrores_servTarjeta(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "" }));
            setpaseValidacionFormTitularTarjeta("SI");            
        }

        

        if (!stripe || !elements) {
            // Stripe.js has not yet loaded.
            // Make sure to disable form submission until Stripe.js has loaded.
            return;
        }
```

Aqui viene la parte donde verifico que hayan pasado todas las validaciones de cada campo del formulario para recién empezar a crear el pago con el código de Stripe
La función await stripe.createPaymentMethod({ es el que ocasiona el error, este código es extraído de la documentación de Stripe para crear un método de pago, en realidad luego de que paymentMethod se llene con data siguen otros métodos de llamada await de Stripe que los he borrado dejando solo este, debido a que incluso solo con este await ya recibo el error, y quiero que puedan ayudarme como limpiar la tarea asyncrona.

```
        if (paseValidacionFormTitularTarjeta == "SI" && paseValidacionFormCorreoTarjeta == "SI" && paseValidacionFormTarjeta == "SI" && paseValidacionFormFechaExpTarjeta == "SI" && paseValidacionFormCvcTarjeta == "SI" && paseValidacionFormCiudadTarjeta == "SI" && paseValidacionFormCodigoPostalTarjeta == "SI")
        {    
            const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardNumberElement);
            const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
                type: 'card',
                card: cardElement,
                billing_details: {
                    email: camposDatosTarjeta.correo_tarjeta,
                    name: camposDatosTarjeta.titular_tarjeta,
                    address: {
                        city: camposDatosTarjeta.ciudad_tarjeta,
                        country: 'PE',
                        postal_code: camposDatosTarjeta.codigo_postal_tarjeta,
                    }
                },               
            });

            if (error) {                
            } 
            else 
            {
```

Aquí es donde al momento que actualizo el Stepper al número 3, que sería el último paso y es cuando aparece el error entonces quiero saber como limpiar las tareas asyncronas antes de pasar a un nuevo componente, todo debe ser realizado en mi función de handlesubmit sin usar useEffect,

```
               setCurrentStep(3);                   
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <div id="contenedor-detalles-tarjeta">
            <Container component="main" maxWidth="md" justify="center">
                <label className="detalles-tarjeta-titulo">
                <Typography >
                    <span >Detalles de tarjeta</span>
                </Typography>
            </label>
            <form id="realizar-pago-visa" onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>

           Aquí he borrado porciones de código , pero solo es la creación de los campos del formulario de pago

         <Button type="submit" className="confirmar-orden" name="confirmar_orden" disabled= 
         {!stripe} variant="contained" color="primary">Confirmar orden</Button> 
         </form>
         </Container>
        </div>
    );
}
```

osea cuando paso al componente final y desaparezco los componentes de Element y el CheckoutForm2 es ahí donde recibo el error a causa del await Stripe... y dice que estoy intentando actualizar un estado en un componente que ya no existe, sin embargo cuando ocurre setCurrentStep(3); yo ya no actualizo nada más y no entiendo por que recibo el error, entonces creo que el error se refiere al await y pide que debo limpiar también la tarea asyncrona del await y no sé como hacerlo , debo limpiar todo mediante el mismo handleSubmit, sin usar useEffect ya que para mi caso eso no aplica .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme por que no encuentro solución alguna

Comment: Estás en so en español traduce por favor

Comment: el titulo tambien.. y te quedoun parrafo

Comment: listo ya corregí todo en español , también adjunte una imagen al final para que puedan ver mas claramente cuando recibo el error, espero puedan ayudarme si saben del tema , ya que no he logrado hasta ahora solucionarlo